# is it possible to fully qualify a function operator in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a binary operator such as magrittr %>%. I can invoke it like

```
library(magrittr)

a %>% b
```

How can I use a fully qualified expression instead of library, as from this example:

```
a magrittr::%>% b
```

I tried various combinations but I could not get it to work.

Comment: Is it for a user or developer?

Answer (score 4):

First define `%>%`:

```
`%>%` <- magrittr::`%>%`

# test
3 %>% sum(1)
## [1] 4
```